# org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/login.jsp'

Tags: struts2, tiles

I m new to tiles and strut2.
I am not able to understand that when I use the HTML tag in login.jsp page then it works fine but at the same time if I code in struts tag in login.jsp then it gives an error. why this is happening I am not able to understand. The following code and error are given below ..kindly help me

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
> from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error executing tag: JSPException
> including path '/baseLayout.jsp'.
>
> root cause
>
> org.apache.tiles.TilesException: JSPException including path
> '/baseLayout.jsp'.
>
> root cause
>
> org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path
> '/baseLayout.jsp'.
>
> root cause
>
> org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path
> '/login.jsp'.
>
> root cause
>
> The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by
> using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only
> usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which
> initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown
> location]
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
> available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.

web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
   id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
   <display-name>Struts2Example15</display-name>
    
   <context-param>
   <param-name>
      org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
   </param-name>
   <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/tiles.xml
   </param-value>
   </context-param>

   <listener>
   <listener-class>
      org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
   </listener-class>
   </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   
   <filter>
   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
   <filter-class>
   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
   </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

   
</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
 
    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.view.tiles.TilesResult"/> 
            </result-types>  
        <action name="loginAction" class="package_entry.loginAction" method="execute">
            <result name="getin">welcome.jsp</result>
             <result name="user_login">user_login.jsp</result>
        
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <%@page language="java"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
    <tiles:insertTemplate template="/baseLayout.jsp">
        <tiles:putAttribute name="tiles" value="this is tes framework" type="string"/> 
            <tiles:putAttribute name="header" value="/header.jsp" /> 
            <tiles:putAttribute name="menu" value="/menu.jsp" /> 
            <tiles:putAttribute name="body" value="/body.jsp" /> 
            <tiles:putAttribute name="footer" value="/footer.jsp" />   
    </tiles:insertTemplate>
```

menu.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<a href="loging.jsp">Login</a><br>
<a href="registring.jsp">Register</a><br>
<a href="contacting.jsp">Contact</a><br>
```

loging.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<tiles:insertDefinition name="login.def"/>
```

tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
 
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
<put-attribute name="title"  value="Template"/>
<put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp"/>
<put-attribute name="menu"   value="/menu.jsp"/>
<put-attribute name="body"   value="/body.jsp"/>
<put-attribute name="footer"   value="/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>
 
<definition name="login.def" extends="baseLayout">
<put-attribute name="title"  value="Login form"/>
<put-attribute name="body"   value="/login.jsp"/>
</definition>
 
<definition name="register.def" extends="baseLayout">
<put-attribute name="title"  value="Register"/>
<put-attribute name="body"   value="/register.jsp"/>
</definition>
 
<definition name="contact.def" extends="baseLayout">
<put-attribute name="title"  value="contact"/>
<put-attribute name="body"   value="/contact.jsp"/>
</definition>
 
</tiles-definitions>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <s:form>
            <s:textfield name="email_id" label="Email"/>
            <s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
            <s:submit value="login"/>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you going to that page without going through an action?

Comment: yay..according to my knowledge i access the page through an action..you can also check my code as i already mentioned above.

Comment: had it been i access the jsp page(using html tag) directly then it wouldnt display the page but when i used strut tag then it reflect error

Comment: `This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter.` That *is* the error message. Also, `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher` has been deprecated since S2.1 or so.

Comment: will u please tell me .if this is the error ,then how should i resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have to add the relative path to each definition

For instance change

```
value="/login.jsp"/>
```

in

```
value="/WEB-INF/path/to/your/login.jsp"/>
```

Therefore:

```
<definition name="login.def" extends="baseLayout">
   <put-attribute name="title"  value="Login form"/>
   <put-attribute name="body"   value="/WEB-INF/path/to/your/login.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

In addition I do not see anywhere your tile render and configurer. Have you added tiles into your pom?

Comment: pom..??? i am not using maven  and am using netbeans 8.0.2 and glassfish server 4.1

Comment: Well have you added apache tiles jars to your project?

Comment: i have Strut2jar which constitute( commmon-beanutil, commons-io,strut2-tiles-plugin, tiles-api etc) jar files which are  neccessary for  tiles

Comment: bytheway i have gone through dozen of struts2 tiles tutorial all have recommended to use strut2 jar only

Comment: can anyoune help me ,..i m still struggling the same problem